# why pdf upload fails on codeigniter 1.7.2?

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

i have same problem. other files doc, xls uploads fine. but pdf uploading gives error. “The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.”
in config/mimnes.php i have:

```
'pdf'    =>    array('application/pdf', 'application/x-download', 'application/download'),
```

in controllers i have:

```
function upload_file($type, $upload_type)
{
    $this->load->library('upload');
    //upload file
    switch($upload_type){
        case "image":
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpg|png|pdf';
            $config['max_size'] = '3000';
            $config['max_width'] = '3224';
            $config['max_height'] = '1268';
        break;
        case "doc":
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/pages/doc/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|doc|docx|xls|ppt';
            $config['max_size'] = '3000';
            $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
        break;
    }
    foreach($_FILES as $key => $value)
    {
        if( ! empty($value['name']))
        {
                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($key))
                {
                $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                $this->session->set_flashdata('flashError', $errors);

                }
                else
                {
                     $this->page_model->process_file($type, $upload_type);
                }
         }
    }
}
```

any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
$this->load->library('upload');
```

Then add this line after end of switch block and before foreach block

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

You are loading the upload library and then setting config values, which has no effect.

Your modified function should look like this:

```
function upload_file($type, $upload_type)
{
    //upload file
    switch($upload_type){
        case "image":
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpg|png|pdf';
            $config['max_size'] = '3000';
            $config['max_width'] = '3224';
            $config['max_height'] = '1268';
        break;
        case "doc":
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/pages/doc/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|doc|docx|xls|ppt';
            $config['max_size'] = '3000';
            $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
        break;
    }

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    foreach($_FILES as $key => $value)
    {
        if( ! empty($value['name']))
        {
                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($key))
                {
                $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                $this->session->set_flashdata('flashError', $errors);

                }
                else
                {
                     $this->page_model->process_file($type, $upload_type);
                }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have initialized config like $this->upload->initialize($config); no need to do the same thing twice.

Comment: ya $upload_type is correct. but today what i figured out is : i am able to upload file alternatively. if i upload a doc file and a pdf file then both uploads. and if i upload pdf file only it doesnt. what may be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as well but figured out that some PDF files are sent as type **application/octet-stream** in FireFox. I don't know why. But try to open mimetype.php add it to the mimetype array of   pdf file like this :

*'pdf'    =>  array('application/pdf', 'application/x-download', 'application/binary', 'application/octet-stream'),*

Answer (score 0):

Are you using FireFox? I had the same problem, originated by FF. The mimetype reported is application/binary, so you can chage that in mimes.php

```
'pdf'   =>  array('application/pdf', 'application/x-download', 'application/binary'),
```

that should solve the problem.

Comment: not at all. it works fine in ie but not in firefox. i m using 3.6.13

Comment: to see what is being precessed, can you add a print_r($_FILES) and copy the output?

Comment: Here is mine:Array ( [nuevoarchivo] => Array ( [name] => 110_2008.pdf [type] => application/pdf [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpDLUXpE [error] => 0 [size] => 30680 ) )

Comment: inside 
   case "image": 
you have included   
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpg|png|pdf';

may be it's failing when you try to upload a pdf as an image, because of size restrictions and so.